# Const constructor vs. static final canonical values

Tags: dart

As per [this excellent explanation](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html) `const` expressions in Dart are "deeply immutable" meaning that nothing inside can ever change and therefore the entire expression will always denote the same thing. This is useful for the compiler, because it can generate the entire object graph once and re-use it every time such an expression occurs, and it is useful for the programmer to know that such an expression –even when it is deeply nested– still follows value-semantics and won't do anything behind my back.

I am using those optimizations by the compiler to use a well-structured object model (instead of hand-encoding it in a bit-vector, for example) and still get good performance. Since we can get some of those benefits also by "explicitly hashing" some values by making them run-time constants with the `static final` idiom, the question arises which of the two is good style to use in which case?

Consider the following example:

```
enum ShaftType { RING, SUN, CARRIER }

class Shaft {
  final int index;
  final ShaftType type;

  Shaft(this.type, this.index) {
    assert((type == ShaftType.CARRIER) == (index == null));
  }
  const Shaft.CARRIER()
      : type = ShaftType.CARRIER,
        index = null;
  const Shaft.RING(this.index) : type = ShaftType.RING;
  const Shaft.SUN(this.index) : type = ShaftType.SUN;
}

class GearPath {
  final Shaft input, output, fixed;

  GearPath({this.input, this.output, this.fixed}) {
    // input and output must be set
    assert(null != input && null != output);

    // fixed shaft can't be anything else
    assert(fixed != input && fixed != output);
  }

  GearPath.carrierToFirstRingFixedSun(int i)
      : input = const Shaft.CARRIER(),
        output = const Shaft.RING(0),
        fixed = new Shaft.SUN(i) {}

  static final singleFixedSunUp = new GearPath(
    input: const Shaft.CARRIER(),
    output: const Shaft.RING(0),
    fixed: const Shaft.SUN(0),
  );

  static final directDrive = new GearPath(
    input: const Shaft.CARRIER(),
    output: const Shaft.CARRIER(),
    fixed: null,
  );

  // ... 
}
```

I can't make the main `Shaft(..)` and `GearStage(..)` constructors `const` because I want to check some constraints, but I can provide special-case constructors (such as `Shaft.SUN(int i)`, `Shaft.CARRIER()`) which comply with those constraints (at least partially) by design and provide users legible shorthands for those common values.

On the other hand, when a `const` constructor would have no arguments, then I can as well write it as a `static final` member as I have done with `GearStage.directDrive`. If all users refer to this static member instead of re-creating the value again, we also get the benefit of sharing memory and fast comparisons (reference to same object). I can't declare the right-side of this definition as const, because it uses the non-const constructor, but developers can see from context that this is indeed a constant value and not global mutable singleton hidden in the static field. So for practical purposes it should be just as good as a const constructor, right?

Since I haven't found this described any where as a best practice my question is simply if this is indeed a good way to combine and trade-off between `const` constructors and `static final` "named value instances"?

Finally, I wonder if there is a way to declare `GearPath.carrierToFirstRingFixedSun(int i)` also as a const constructor? Currently I can't because `const Shaft.SUN(i)` complains about `i` not being constant.

([full code of example](https://gitlab.com/matey-jack/planetary_gears/blob/master/lib/model.dart))

Answer (score 2):

Dart 2 will allow you to have asserts in const constructors (as long as your condition can be computed as a const expression).
Then you will be able to write:

```dart
GearPath({this.input, this.output, this.fixed}) 
  : // input and output must be set
    assert(null != input && null != output),
    // fixed shaft can't be anything else
    assert(!identical(fixed, input) && !identical(fixed, output));
```

Until then, you can't have both validation and const expressions.

You still will not be able to make `GearPath.carrierToFirstRingFixedSun(int i)` const because it `i` is not constant. The `const Shaft.SUN(i)` is still not a valid const expression, even if `i` is the parameter of a const constructor. Each `const Constructor(...)` invocation must still create exactly one object, even if it occurs in the initializer list of another const constructor.

As a rule-of-thumb, you should consider whether exposing a value as const instead of final is something you want to commit to. When you make the variable const, it means that someone else can use the value in another const expression, and then changing the variable to final will be a breaking change. Saying that something is `const` is a commitment that you should choose deliberately, not just because you can. So, consider the use-cases of your variable. If you don't see it being used in other const expressions, then just make it final.